# If a proton travels near relativistic speeds does it's charge change in magnitude in its surrounding space?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, inertial-frames, plasma-physics

Fusion reaction hinges on nuclei coming close enough for the strong nuclear force to overcome countering electromagnetic force.

If a proton travels as a plasma and is accelerated to near relativistic speeds does it's charge change in magnitude in its surrounding space?  A change to a proton's countering electromagnetic force might create weak spots in the space surrounding it and increase probability of feeling the strong nuclear force.

I am not in science so forgive my ignorance, yet I am so curious.

Comment: The simple answer is that relativistic protons are very boring relative to what you lay out here. They just are going fast, nothing else.

Comment: Charge is a relativistic invariant.

Comment: I will add to WillO's comment and say that charge density is not a Lorentz invariant.

Answer (score 1):

[At the LHC at CERN,](https://home.cern/science/accelerators/large-hadron-collider) protons hit protons with momenta much higher than the ones that might statistically be attained in a plasma. There is no sign that the basic assumption in the theories that the center of mass system of a reaction can also describe motions given by Lorentz tranformation with no change in the form factors of the particles involved. For example the following examines theoretically the data :

> [Our results imply](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.09564) that the present framework works well in the considered TeV scale, and further applications to other high energy scattering processes, in which the involved strong interaction can be approximated by the Pomeron exchange, are possible.